# jQuery: Easy way to trigger "mousestop" event

Tags: jquery, timer, mouseevent, settimeout, mousemove

HI,

I'm trying to call a function when the mouse stopped moving for x seconds. Actually thats pretty easy with the following code:

```
var timer = null;
$(document).mousemove(function(){
  clearTimeout (timer);
  timer = setTimeout(myfunction, 5000);
});
```

But the mousemove event is called very often, so I get a pretty heavy processor load in Firefox while moving the mouse. Is there an easy way to do the same thing with less function calls???

Thanx!
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Use this and set the delay option for x seconds

http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event

Comment: I was searching for a mousestop event in jQuery API search! :(( Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Usage is the same as [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), but the event only fires after a short, configurable delay.

```
$('myselector').hoverIntent(
        function () { HoverIn(); },
        function () { HoverOut(); }
);
```